# Can I prevent the linker from adding fill bytes?

Tags: c, x86, linker, ld, bare-metal

I am experimenting with some x86 bare metal code, specifically a simple bootloader which loads a second stage etc., all packed into one image.

Right now, I have the following linker script:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
        . = 0x7c00;
        .boot : {
                boot.o (.boot);
        }
        . = 0x7c00 + 510;
        .magic : {
                SHORT(0xaa55);
        }

        . = 0x10000;
        .text32 : {
                boot.o (.boot32);
                main32.o (.text);
        }
}
```

Idea here being, that the code loaded by the first stage should be assumed to run at `0x10000`.
The linker will fill the gap between `.boot` and `.text32` with zeros.
This is somewhat useless, as the first stage is loading this anyway, so the padding is not needed.
Can I somehow make the linker ignore the gap? (As if I was copying two binary blobs after each other). Ideally it would suffice if the `.text32` section starts at offset 512 in the resulting file. BUT the code should be linked as if it would start at `0x10000`.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Create different memory regions starting at your addresses and place the sections into the appropriate ones. Linker does not fill anything unless it is told to.

Comment: Thx, I kind of got what I want using `.text32 0x10000 : AT ( ADDR (.magic) + SIZEOF (.magic) ) { ..`. Can you give an example of the solution you suggested?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the linker switch `-n, --nmagic`. Without this switch, the sections are page aligned, so the linker fills the space between with zeros.

(The following example is for `ARM`, but the behavior from `-n, --nmagic` should be the same on `x86`.)

**Without `-n, --nmagic`**

*ELF Header and symbol table:*

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8000299
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          9012 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000200, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         3
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         11
  Section header string table index: 10

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        08000000 001000 00038c 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS        24000000 002000 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        24000000 002000 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS          24000000 002000 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 5] .heap             NOBITS          24000000 002000 07f000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 6] .stack            NOBITS          2407f000 002000 001000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 7] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 002000 000021 00      0   0  1
  [ 8] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 002024 000200 10      9  14  4
  [ 9] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 002224 0000bd 00      0   0  1
  [10] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0022e1 000051 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), y (purecode), p (processor specific)
```

*File size:*

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jk jk 9452 Oct 22 04:42 test.elf
```

**With `-n, --nmagic`**

*ELF Header and symbol table:*

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8000299
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          1880 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000200, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         3
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         11
  Section header string table index: 10

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        08000000 000094 000390 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS        24000000 000424 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        24000000 000424 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS          24000000 000424 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 5] .heap             NOBITS          24000000 000424 07f000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 6] .stack            NOBITS          2407f000 000424 001000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 7] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 000424 000021 00      0   0  1
  [ 8] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 000448 000200 10      9  14  4
  [ 9] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 000648 0000bd 00      0   0  1
  [10] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 000705 000051 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), y (purecode), p (processor specific)
```

*File size:*

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jk jk 2320 Oct 22 04:50 test.elf
```

As you can see with the switch `-n, --nmagic` the resulting binary is `7132` bytes smaller.

Comment: The padding in the OP's case isn't just for page-alignment of sections.  They have two parts with a gap between the addresses they should be linked for (where they'll be loaded), but they want them contiguous in the flat binary output file.  Because despite the lack of metadata, it won't be loaded as a single flat region.